# if-else shortcut surprise

Tags: c#, syntax

i was totally surprised that the 3rd solution doesn't work (Compiler says: `; is missing`).

```
bool isFoobar = true;

isFoobar == true ? isFoobar = false : isFoobar = true; // [1] works
( isFoobar ? isFoobar = false : isFoobar = true ); // [2] works
isFoobar ? isFoobar = false : isFoobar = true; // [3] failed
```

Ehm, why does the last one not work?

Comment: You need comparison to work properly: isFoobar == true 
or some expression that returns bool value

Comment: this is not true infinity - the ternary operator takes a boolean to decide which case to assign, same with if. `bool == true` is code smell - you don't need to check if a boolean is true or false, because the result of the comparision will be the boolean itself.

Comment: Could you edit this to show a complete code block where your two "work"ing examples actually compile?

Comment: @AakashM no i can't, because they don't compile. I never compiled it like i see a moment ago. It was just the syntax-checker. If i would have compiled it, i had seen the problem myself :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I try the code, neither of those work. You can't use an expression like that as a statement.

If you use the expressions as expressions, all three work:

```
bool isFoobar = true;
bool x;

x = isFoobar == true ? isFoobar = false : isFoobar = true;
x = ( isFoobar ? isFoobar = false : isFoobar = true );
x = isFoobar ? isFoobar = false : isFoobar = true;
```

If you only want to use it as a shortcut for if, and don't want to use the result, you are using it the wrong way. The conditional operator should be used for expressions, not instead of an if statement.

Answer (score 7):

None of those is correct. I get compiler errors with them all.

The correct syntax is:

```
isFoobar = isFoobar ? false : true;
```

*update*

The errors I get with your statements are:

1 & 2:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

3:

> Invalid expression term ':'
>
> ; expected
>
> ; expected

Comment: you are right! i don't make the assignment to the variable and then all three variants are working. doh!

Comment: would the down voter care to comment? What have I said wrong?

Answer (score 7):

A better solution is:

```
isFoobar = !isFoobar;
```

Comment: I don't think he meant that he is trying to negate isFooBar he's just using it as a short example of the ternary operator failing unexpectedly.

Comment: He wasn't using the ternary statement properly in the first place. I merely gave an alternative solution to his example. If isFoobar was true, make it false, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

under .net 3.5 this work and compile

```
        bool isFoobar = true;

        var a = isFoobar == true ? isFoobar = false : isFoobar = true; // [1] works
        var b = ( isFoobar ? isFoobar = false : isFoobar = true ); // [2] works
        var c = isFoobar ? isFoobar = false : isFoobar = true; // [3] works
```

a, b and c are type boolean

Comment: Yep, none of those 3 lines were valid C# in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You are using it the wrong way. The ternary operator is there to assign a variable based upon a predicate, not to execute code in the two cases.

```
  var obj = predicate ? true_case : false_case; //if predicate is true, true_case will be assigned to obj.
```

Comment: This. The ternary operator is not a universal _if-else shortcut_ as the question title suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken - none of them compile. Try commenting out the third line and see what happens. The true/false part of the ternary statement needs to return a value, which you are not doing.

Answer (score 0):

If statement is only like below:

```
isFoobar ? isFoobar = false : isFoobar = true;
```

It gives same error as in the question,

If statement is like:

```
isFoobar ? (isFoobar = false) : (isFoobar = true);
```

Error: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement